# Multi-way clustering

Tags: econometrics

I want to understand when and why multi-way clustering is necessary.

Could anyone give a good example that provides intuition of when and why to use multi-way clustering that also illustrates why clustering at a group level is not sufficient?

Comment: Paper: [Robust Inference With Multi-Way Clustering](http://www.nber.org/papers/t0327.pdf) Leaving this for anyone else who stumbles across this page looking for information on clustering. I will also provide an outline of the paper once I have a bit of time this week.

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look at the empirical limitations of clustering: http://economics.mit.edu/files/11355, in other words: when is clustering a bad idea.